# Should I use session for saving user data? Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and I think sessions would be the best thing for my use case, but I'm not sure, maybe there are better possibilities?

This is my application simplified:
Users should be able to select any number of train connections out of a database, and my application returns the best average mobile phone operator for their connections.

My models would be the following:

- User, in which all the connections are saved
- Connection, in which the quality of the mobile net for different operators is saved

And to save the users (and thus their choosen connections) I would have used sessions, which save the user_id.

Is this possible and recommended?

Comment: Your application scope is very clear but I can't figured out what you were saying in the last... Do you know when to use session? and database save?

Comment: as I said im not sure. Is it possible to achieve my goals without using sessions? how can I distinguish between to different users using my website at the same time?

Comment: If you want your user preference to save and later use then db is the best choice. Also if you don't care about later use then session is best...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user's choices to persist longer than a single session, (i.e. I can come back to your app another time and be able to retrieve my choices), use a database to store it. You can look at https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_start_project/#set-up-a-database and https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/

Otherwise, if you do not want their choices to persist, then by all means use sessions.